# How to Exclude a GridDataItem from Collection of GridDataItems in foreach Loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I use a RadGrid control in an ASP.net project. This is a grid control from [Telerik UI](https://www.telerik.com/).I have an instance of this control and i want to iterate through it's `SelectedItems`.
it's something like this:

```
RadGrid mygrd
foreach (GridDataItem item in mygrd.SelectedItems)
{
//Do Something with item

}
```

`mygrd.SelectedItems` is a collection of GridDataItem. Every GridDataItem has columns witch are are defined in the control. Now i want to exclude an specific item with an specific value in one of it's columns. something like this:

```
foreach (GridDataItem item in mygrd.SelectedItems (Except if item["column1"] == "somethingSpecfic"))
{

//Do Something with item

}
```

I am looking a convenient way if exists, so not to use `IF ELSE`. Also I was Looking to use Some LINQ, But actually there is no `where` method under `SelectedItems`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional statement:

```
foreach (GridDataItem item in mygrd.SelectedItems) { 
    if(item["column1"] != ”somethingSpecific”)
        //Do Something with item 
}
```

**UPDATE:**

okay, here is LINQ version, as asked in comments

```
foreach (GridDataItem item in mygrd.SelectedItems.Where(i => i["column1"] != ”somethingSpecific”)) { 
    //Do Something with item 
}
```

Comment: yes it is the simplest way possible. but i'm rather looking for a way more convenient. like what we have in LINQ.

Comment: I've updated post with Linq version. But it's basics of Linq and if you really want to use it in your code I suggest you to spend some time to understand it.

Comment: there is no "where" method under "SelectedItems".